# Jekyll страницы по дате example.com/2018-05-20/

Tags: ruby, jekyll

Как создать страницы на Jekyll по дате без создания самих страниц?
Пример: `example.com/2018-05-20/`
Если есть посты отображаются for posts, если нет то не страница ошибки, а свой код ошибки на этой же странице.

```
{% if ispage %}
  {% for posts %}
    ...
  {% endfor %}
{% else %}
  Нет постов
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Пару лет назад искал аналогичное решение для списков постов с отдельными метками (тегами). Никаких решений без плагинов и JS не нашёл.

Comment: @D-side да даже с плагинами бы, есть какие-то на примете?

Comment: Если б я рассматривал с плагинами, я б забил и написал. Я рубист, в конце концов :| Но я искал для гитхаба, где плагины нельзя.

Comment: @D-side я на гитлабе хощу, там вроде работают плагины, если я всё знаю о плагинах.

Comment: Видимо, не всё: https://help.github.com/articles/adding-jekyll-plugins-to-a-github-pages-site/

Comment: @D-side gitlab.com , не github

Comment: А, прошу прощения. Да, на гитлабе гораздо более свободно организован процесс, там любым генератором можно пользоваться.

Comment: @D-side есть возможность написать такой плагин?

Comment: Для этого есть вся мощь Ruby, конечно возможность существует. Можете глянуть [в `jekyll-tagging`](https://github.com/pattex/jekyll-tagging), где делается похожее.

Comment: @D-side не понял, что там есть похожего с моим случаем?

Comment: Там тоже генерируются страницы с группами постов по заданным свойствам, в вашем случае это дата, а там наличие тега/метки.

Comment: @D-side мне типо этот плагин переписать под дату? если да, то факт в том что я руби не знаю. если нет, то в каждом посту типо теги должны быть, но факт в том что год не может быть постов и тупо будет 404 при  `example.com/2018-02-04/`

Comment: Да. Готовые плагины мне неизвестны, а дорваться написать такой я смогу нескоро, есть более приоритетные вещи.

Comment: @D-side за сколько ты сможешь написать такой плагин. или подскажи платформу где можно заказать такой.

Comment: Я думаю, что работы немного, но если вам срочно, на любой фриланс-бирже любой рубист, умеющий работать с отладчиком и читать документацию, с задачей справится. Возможность изучить руби самостоятельно тоже списывать сходу не стоит, основы постигаются быстро.

Answer (score 1):

По идеи нужно запустить цикл перебора постов и создать массив в который будут класться посты по необходимому вам условию. Потом просто перебирать массив другим циклом. Думаю ликвид позволил бы такое